# Which sorting algorithm is best for large datasets and long key?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

Consider a dataset with large no of elements to be sorted where each key is a long integer value, then which sorting algorithm is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Quick sort algorithm generally is the best for large data sets and long keys. This is because in the average case the time complexity is O(n logn). But, in sorting algorithms it's best that you always analise the type of data you will apply the algorithm and then decide wich one you gonna use.